# How to populate TextField via click listener 'Vaadin'

Tags: java, css, vaadin7

I am new to Vaadin and I'm attempting to add text to a text entered by user to a text field.  Also is there a vaadin object that I can use to automatically resize the textfield horizontally if user enters a big name.

For example: John fits nicely in the text field but Bobwehadababyitsaboy whole name will not be seen in the text field.  Below is the code I have so far in populated the text field on button click.

```
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

final TextField name = new TextField();
name.setCaption("Type your name here:");

final TextField message = new TextField();
message.setCaption(name.getValue());

Button button = new Button("Click Me");
button.addClickListener( e -> {
    layout.addComponent(message);
});

layout.addComponents(name, button);
```

Comment: Which text should be added and where? Regarding the size, if you expect to have a bigger chunk of text, you can opt for a [text area](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-textarea.html).

Comment: I would like to add the name value inside the message text field.  As of now the 'empty' message text area appears under the name text field after button click.  Can't I do something like if the name is bigger than 10 then stretch the message text field?

Comment: As per the [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-textfield.html), you can use the `setValue(string)` method of the TextField, eg: `message.setValue(name.getValue())`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `TextChangeListener`, this will allow you to check the length of the text entered and resize the textfield accordingly.

```
TextField tf = new TextField();
tf.addTextChangeListener(new TextChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void textChange(TextChangeEvent event) {
        // 
        int len = event.getText().length();
        if (len > 100) {
            event.getComponent().setWidth("350px");
        }
        else if (len > 50) {
            event.getComponent().setWidth("250px");
        }
        else {
            event.getComponent().setWidth("150px");
        }   
    }
});
tf.setTextChangeEventMode(TextChangeEventMode.EAGER);
```